Vue - Two Reactive Arrays: How do I change the state of one and not the other?
Both arrays are rendered on the UI. The second array ("array2") is a modification of the first ("array1"). I want to modify array2 without array1 changing at all, but haven't figured out how. It always reflects the same changes as array2.
I've tried pushing array1 to a "transitionArray", modifying that, then pushing to array2:
   for (let i = 0; i < this.array1.length; i++) {
        transitionArray.push(this.array1[i])
      }

   (modification...)

  for (let i = 0; i < transitionArray.length; i++) {
        this.array2.push(transitionArray[i])
      }

And then I tried putting array2 in its own method to try and separate array1 and array2 further:
   for (let i = 0; i < this.array1.length; i++) {
        transitionArray.push(this.array1[i])
      }

   (modification...)  


   this.updateCurrentUserSettings(transitionArray)

      },
      
      updateCurrentUserSettings(array) {

      for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        this.array2.push(array[i])
      }
    }

But array1 still updates the same as array2. This seems like an easy fix but for some reason I just can't find it.

This is a case for deep cloning vs shallow cloning. There are a ton of resources that explain it very cleary. Such as: https://www.javatpoint.com/shallow-copy-and-deep-copy-in-javascript#:~:text=Conclusion-,In%20JavaScript%2C%20there%20are%20two%20ways%20to%20copy%20objects%3A%20shallow,and%20nested%20objects%20or%20arrays.

The question requires https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve . The problem is in code you didn't show, "modification...". It sounds like you modify objects that are stored inside arrays. Objects are passed by reference in JS, unless you explicitly clone them. It's unrelated to arrays (which are objects too, but this isn't relevant here)

Estus Flask, it is an array of objects, I should have been clearer there. The modification has the option of modifying the objects in the array, or removing certain objects, the shallow cloning/deep cloning solution suggested by Wimanicesir does appear to solve my issue so far, thank you
